# Retrieving statistics for stored procedure, SelectRows is always 0

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to collect statistics on some SQL queries. 
I'm using **RetrieveStatistics()** method of **SqlDbConnection** class to get statistics and **ExecuteReader()** method of **SqlCommand** to run query.
**RetrieveStatistics()** method returns dictionary filled with statistics on the query executed.
When I'm running regular query, **SelectRows** propety of dictionary contains actual number of rows returned  by query. But when I'm running stored procedure, SelectRows is always zero, although reader definitely contains rows.

I call **ResetStatistics()** before each query and **StatisticsEnabled** is set to true.

Here's my Powershell code:

```
### Stored procedure

$cn = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection
$cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$cn.StatisticsEnabled = $true
$cmd = $cn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[spGetXXXX]"
$cmd.CommandType = "StoredProcedure"
$cn.Open()
$cmd.ExecuteReader()
# several rows returned
$cn.RetrieveStatistics()

Name                           Value
----                           -----
BytesReceived                  300
SumResultSets                  1
ExecutionTime                  5
Transactions                   0
BuffersReceived                1
IduRows                        0
ServerRoundtrips               1
PreparedExecs                  0
BytesSent                      132
SelectCount                    1
CursorOpens                    0
ConnectionTime                 51299
Prepares                       0
SelectRows                     0
UnpreparedExecs                1
NetworkServerTime              3
BuffersSent                    1
IduCount                       0

### Regular SQL query
$cn2 = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection
$cn2.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$cn2.StatisticsEnabled = $true
$cmd2 = $cn2.CreateCommand()
$cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM XXXX"
$cn2.Open()
$cmd2.ExecuteReader()

#rows returned

$cn2.RetrieveStatistics()

Name                           Value
----                           -----
BytesReceived                  12357
SumResultSets                  1
ExecutionTime                  12
Transactions                   0
BuffersReceived                2
IduRows                        0
ServerRoundtrips               1
PreparedExecs                  0
BytesSent                      98
SelectCount                    1
CursorOpens                    0
ConnectionTime                 11407
Prepares                       0
SelectRows                     112
UnpreparedExecs                1
NetworkServerTime              0
BuffersSent                    1
IduCount                       0
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two queries is that after stored procedure call reader stays open, and row number statistics is not updated.

So the correct code would be like:

```
$connectionn.ResetStatistics()
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
$reader.Close() # !
$connection.RetrieveStatistics()
```